# Adding dependency from local repository - m2e

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I am using eclipse with m2e plugin and I have in my home folder my local repository. m2e sees it because when I go to

```
Window->Show View->Maven->Maven Repositories
```

I can see my local repo, but when I try to add dependency to my project I need to manually write group-id and artefact-id. Surely there must be a way to add dependency through some menu which lists jars in the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy to do, two ways:

- Double click the POM file so that it opens in the *Maven POM Editor*. The *Dependencies* tab will allow you to add the dependency with search capabilities.
- You can do the same by right-clicking the project, then *Maven > Add Dependency*

The *Add Dependency* dialog has a *Search* field which allows you to start typing and will show matching artifacts. Start typing *spring*, and it will show you everything Spring-related. You can then pick the desired artifact and version from the list of results and it will be added to your POM file.